# Remove the hour,minute and seconds from date gotten from server as JSON

Tags: java, android, json, date, time

I am getting some JSON data from server that includes dates too. But it shows the date like this `2017-07-20 00:00:00` but I want to just see the date like this:`2017-07-20`, and i checked the previous questions about this issue but all of them were based on the date in the android side. And the problem is that I get the date as JSON and because of that I don't know how to remove Time from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to simple parse this string like this?

```
String date_string = "2017-07-20 00:00:00";
String[] parsed = date_string.split(" ");
String your_wanted_string = parsed[0];
System.out.println(your_wanted_string);
```

**EDIT**

1. You have to convert string into `Date` like here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216767/1979882
2. Convert Date to milliseconds. Or use Calendar class.
3. Calculate the difference between the values.

An example:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-get-time-in-milliseconds-in-java/

```
public class TimeMilisecond {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    String dateInString = "22-01-2015 10:20:56";
    Date date = sdf.parse(dateInString);

    System.out.println(dateInString);
    System.out.println("Date - Time in milliseconds : " + date.getTime());

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    System.out.println("Calender - Time in milliseconds : " + calendar.getTimeInMillis());

  }
}
```

Comment: @Shayea , approve the answer if it was helpful

Comment: and can you please tell me how to get the difference between two dates got with JOSN from server?

Answer (score 0):

```
 String date_from_json="your date goes here";
 parseDate(date_from_json);

        public String parseDate(String s) {
        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        Date date = null;
        String str = null;

    try {
        date = inputFormat.parse(s);
        str = outputFormat.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my javascript function to do this task from client side:

```
function formatDate(dateString) {
  var date = new Date("2017-07-20 00:00:00"),
    dd = date.getDate(),
    mm = date.getMonth() + 1,
    yyyy = date.getFullYear();
  mm = mm < 10 ? '0' + mm : mm;
  return dd + '-' + mm +'-' + yyyy;
}
```

call:

var dateStr = formatDate("2017-07-20 00:00:00");

[demo](http://jsbin.com/dumuhivibu/edit?js,console,output)